# Text pasted into VS Code Has Spaces but Doesn't Register All Spaces

Tags: visual-studio-code

I pasted some text from a MS Word document into VS Code and when it renders, it doesn't render all the spaces.

I took a closer look and in the image below (screenshot from VS Code) noticed how there is a "dot" between the `y` and the `a`, but there is no "dot" between the `a` and the `T`. When this renders, the `a` and the `T` are right next to each other. Any idea why this happens or how to fix?

[image: Zoomed-in view of some text]

I tried modifying `settings.json` to include:

```
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

But that didn't fix my problem. Has anybody ever seen this before, any ideas?

Comment: Copy and paste to notepad and then from there to VS Code. notepad does not render special formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was considering that, but I was hoping not to add another step to our process. I will def do it if I can't find another solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you know whether this is a space ('\u0020') or some other character? If it's not actually a space, you *really* should add that extra step to your process. You can check if you search for a space in VS code and whether this shows up as selected.